# Some Chinese characters are not shown properly IE, FF, Chrome

Tags: html, browser, cjk

I tried it in several workstations, sometimes the Characters are displayed properly, sometimes only the last part is displayed. Any idea what is causing this? Any solution?

Here is the HTML:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20727629/chi/chi.html

Here is the image of browser with issue:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20727629/chi/chi_issue.gif

Here is the image of browser showing Chinese characters correctly:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20727629/chi/chi.gif

I've tried several things:

1. In Windows, setting Regional Settings Format and Language to Chinese (Hong Kong Sar) sometimes fix it for Firefox (it worked in Windows Server 2003, and Windows 7), but IE and Chrome still displays squares or blank for some Chinese chars. Also it didn't work in Windows XP machine I tried.
2. For XP, In Regional Settings installed files East Asian languages but it didn't fix the problem.
3. In IE, I tried Tools -> Internet Options, setting Font of Chinese to MingLiu or other Chinese fonts. Didn't work.

Tested in the ff environment (English OS):

- Windows 7

  -Works in FF after setting Regional settings to Chinese. IE and Chrome still don't display it correctly.
- Windows Server 2003

  -Works in FF after setting Regional settings to Chinese. IE and Chrome still don't display it correctly.
- Windows XP

  -Problem FF, Chrome, IE
- Ubuntu

  -Problem

Comment: Did you try to change the font in Chrome? In Chrome put this in the address bar and change to relevant font. chrome://settings/fonts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me, that many of these characters are in the [Unicode Private Use Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29). If and how those characters are displayed is highly platform- and font-dependend.

My FF on Linux shows the same rendering as the issue graphic. It means, that there is no character in the list of tried fonts to render the codepoint, and a fallback is used.

The characters, as far as I can oversee, are also present as other codepoints. Use these instead of the Private Use ones, and your chances to get the text rendered will much improve.

For example, you use U+F303 for the first character, the correct one would be [U+31C0](http://decodeunicode.org/en/u+31c0).

Comment: I didn't know about Unicode Private Use Area. Thanks for that info. Do you know how I can convert them to use the non-private ones?

Comment: That depends, which program created them. The point of the private use area is, that programs can do there, whatever they like. There is no definitive mapping from that to anything else.

Comment: I see, how did you convert the first Character? Do you know Chinese? hehe

Comment: I looked around decodeunicode.org until I found a match for it. And yes, I know a little bit Chinese, so my chances were a bit above average. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try diffrent encoding / character set. You are using UTF-8.

Most of chinese websites use gb2312 (simplified) or Big5 (traditional).

Do you know how to convert UTF-8 text file to diffrent encoding?

Comment: I will try this, and see if it works. Thanks! I use Notepad++ not sure if it supports gb2312.

Comment: I don't think it's an encoding issue. If you compare the last sequences in chi.gif and chi_issue.gif, they are identical. That would not happen, if the text was gb2312.

Comment: I see. If you are correct, how did you know that characters are in Unicode Private Use Area? Any way to determine this AND to convert them?

Comment: Html file must be saved with that character set. Notepad++ is good editor with many charset options.

Comment: you are asking question within your answer. Why

Answer (score 0):

The problematic characters seems to be characters in the Big5-HKSCS charset. Convert them to Unicode.